# IE 11 Print screen issue

Tags: jquery, events, internet-explorer-11

When page loaded IE 11 doesn't fire event when user pressed Print Screen (keyCode 44)  for first time. But it works fine after other button pressed.

```
var target = isIE8 ? $(document) : $window;
target.on("keyup keydown keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 44) { // 44 -> PrintScreen button code
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: add full code with html or add jsfiddle link?

Comment: You should ask yourself one question: Do I really want to prevent users to capture print-screen? You should know that is impossible.

Comment: There is a lot of logic in js, and the page is pretty big. I have tried reproduce it here [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html).